# Simplify Dataframe by Year and Calculate Percent Change

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, simplify

I have two questions:
What resources do you recommend reading to improve data manipulation capabilities? I've been working with larger datasets and have been struggling to adapt--I feel like I'm hitting a brick wall and don't know where to look (many online resources get too complicated without building foundation).

For example, I am trying to solve this issue. I have a df with millions of rows and I am trying to simplify it and analyze a trend. I have a dput example. I am trying to isolate each ID and grab the minimum value for a given year. (Some IDs have years not available for others). After simplifying that data, I am trying to add a percent change column. Given this is a 20+ year time series, I am ok with ignoring months at this point, as minimum value for a year compared to a minimum to another year should yield a reasonable percent change.

Thanks!

Input:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 5L, 
6L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 16L), .Label = c("2/21/2009", 
"2/22/2009", "2/23/2009", "2/24/2009", "2/25/2009", "2/26/2009", 
"3/2/2011", "3/3/2011", "3/4/2011", "3/5/2010", "3/5/2011", "3/6/2010", 
"3/6/2011", "3/7/2010", "3/7/2011", "3/8/2011"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 
    2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2009L, 2009L, 
    2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2011L), Value = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
    20, 21, 22, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 23, 25, 27)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date", "Year", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

Expected output:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
3L), .Label = c("2/21/2009", "2/25/2009", "3/2/2011", "3/5/2010", 
"3/6/2011"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L), Value = c(10, 16, 5, 6, 8, 10), Percent.Increase = c(NA, 
0.6, -0.6875, NA, 0.333333333, 0.25)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", 
"Year", "Value", "Percent.Increase"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: As far as what to read goes, the data.table vignettes are a good place to start: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started For guidance on how to think about organizing data, I'd recommend Hadley's article https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10 even though it does not use data.table syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', 'Year', we `slice` the `min` "Value" rows within each group, then grouped by 'ID', we create the 'Percent.Increase' by subtracting the 'Value' from `lag` of 'Value' and dividing by the `lag` of 'Value'.

```
res <-  df1 %>%
         group_by(ID, Year) %>%
         slice(which.min(Value)) %>% 
         group_by(ID) %>%
         mutate(Percent.Increase = (Value-lag(Value))/lag(Value))
```

Comment: It is insane how easy you make this. Thank you @akrun! Do you recommend a particular resource/method to learn dplyr?

Comment: @sammyramz I think the best way to understand would be to practice,  commit mistakes, learn from that, and of course read the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Until [*HAVING* clause](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788) is implemented in data.table, this seems to be pretty efficient way:

```
dt[dt[, .I[which.min(Value)],, .(ID, Year)]$V1
   ][, Percent_Increase := {
       tmp <- shift(Value)
       (Value-tmp)/tmp
   }, .(ID)]
```

Check timing on 5e7.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
N = 5e7
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(ID = sample(2L, N, TRUE), 
                Date = sample(16L, N, TRUE), 
                Year = sample(2009:2011, N, TRUE), 
                Value = sample(N/10, N, TRUE))
dt = as.data.table(df)
system.time(
    res <- df %>%
        group_by(ID, Year) %>%
        slice(which.min(Value)) %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>%
        mutate(Percent_Increase = (Value-lag(Value))/lag(Value))    
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.676   2.176   3.847
system.time(
    r <- dt[dt[, .I[which.min(Value)],, .(ID, Year)]$V1,
            ][, Percent_Increase := {
                tmp <- shift(Value)
                (Value-tmp)/tmp
            }, .(ID)]
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.940   0.460   1.334
all.equal(r, as.data.table(res), ignore.col.order = TRUE, check.attributes = FALSE, ignore.row.order = TRUE)
#[1] TRUE
```